# How can I edit the SOAP envelope and header with Perl's SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl, soap-client, wsh, wso2

I'm trying to modify the soapenv:Header to include addressing in my soap request

```
my $header=SOAP::Header->name("Header")->prefix("soap")->uri("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
```

When I send the request:

```
print $soap->call($header, $security->value(\$userToken, $action, $message))->result;
```

I receive the following...

```
<"soap:Header soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
```

I need to try and override the original `<soap:Header>` I need to do the same for the `<soap:Envelope>`

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could help out :-)

Comment: Indent text to mark it up as code. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Shayne: I added code markup to your post, but your sample SOAP is probably wrong now. Please edit it to match reality.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to "call" is the method name, not the header.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in SOAP::Lite called [SOAP::Lite::Packager](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-Lite-0.710.10/lib/SOAP/Lite/Packager.pm). Look at the "Heades_http" Method. I think that is what you want.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your time, the SOAP::Lite::Packager looks to be for HTTP headers only setting the content MIME types etc, this is modifying the SOAP header's not HTTP headers, the SOAP Headers are just plain xml during the transfer.

But thank you for your time :-)